# Can't use smart update (Delta update)

Tags: google-play-store, updates

I have questions about delta update:

- Is delta updates world wide?
- What version of Android work with delta updates?
- Are all apps supported for delta updates?
- Is there any work to do to activate this feature?

I ask this question because I can't use this feature and still have to download whole size of app for updates

Answer (score 2):

Delta updates work with every *file* that have a valid delta file for it to update. The binary `delta2exe` applies that delta file on your old file and updates it to the newer one.

All you need is that *delta* file which you can get (and is applied directly) with the app *CyanDelta*  which works for all **official** releases of *CyanogenMod* and *OmniROM*.

If you have the old and the new file you can easily create your own *delta* file by following the tutorials on how to create *delta* files: eg. [for xDelta](https://code.google.com/p/xdelta/wiki/CommandLineSyntax)

Comment: thanks for your reply but i have xperia non-custom rom and not rooted with 4.3 android

Comment: Then *delta* updates are not possible. You can only do a delta update if both ends (update server like your manufacturer and your phone ('s software)) support that feature.